# How to convert characters to hour type and add?

Tags: powershell, date-time

I have the following list:

```
[string]$list = ('06:33','07:29','11:54')
```

How do I convert it to numeric type and add?:

output expected:

```
25:56
```

Comment: You asked me a question in a comment then it disappeared. Here's a starting point for that new question in case it helps you to formulate a new question to post for substracting.... `$nTime = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 37 -Minutes 30)-(New-TimeSpan -Hours 25 -Minutes 56);
"$(([string]$nTime.TotalHours).split(".")[0]):$($nTime.Minutes)";`. This is very similar to the answer I provided but you'll have to get the hour and minute marks per each timestamp into those `New-TimeSpan` values using split, etc. with applicable index `[0]` and `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string list with the `timespan` values can be `split` by the default space and transformed to an array. Then pipe that over to a `ForEach-Object` loop using the `+=` operator while declaring the `[TimeSpan]$_` to sum all values in the array—or the timespan data set—to a variable (e.g. `$x`).

The `TotalHours` and `Minutes` values can then be used and cast back to a string using `operators` and `split` with the proper index value to get the preferred output.

### PowerShell

```
[timespan]$x = "00:00";
$list.Split() | % { $x += [timespan]$_; };
"$(([string]$x.TotalHours).split(".")[0]):$($x.Minutes)";
```

### Output

```
25:56
```

#### Other clarifying detail

With the above code, after the line `$list.Split() | % { $x += [timespan]$_; };` is run and then you run `$x`, you will see these values populated that are used to get the final output.

**Output values**

```
Days              : 1
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 56
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 933600000000
TotalDays         : 1.08055555555556
TotalHours        : 25.9333333333333
TotalMinutes      : 1556
TotalSeconds      : 93360
TotalMilliseconds : 93360000
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [TimeSpan Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0)

  > **A TimeSpan object** represents a time interval (duration of time or
  > elapsed time) that is measured as a positive or negative number of
  > days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second. The TimeSpan
  > structure can also be used to represent the time of day, but only if
  > the time is unrelated to a particular date.
- [Formatting TimeSpan in PowerShell](https://codez.deedx.cz/posts/format-timespan-powershell/)

  > **TimeSpan** is a structure which represents a time interval. Working with
  > TimeSpans in PowerShell can be similar to .NET, or can be made a
  > little easier by using native PowerShell functionality.
- [Define PowerShell Data Types](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)
- [New-TimeSpan](https://ss64.com/ps/new-timespan.html)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

  > **Key**
  >
  > `strSeparator`  The character used to split up each string, by
  > default whitespace (space/newline/tab)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Variables and Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-variables.html)

  > Operators allow you to assign a value to the variable, or
  > perform
  > mathematical operations:
  >
  > **Operator:**  `+= n`
  >
  > **Description:** Increase value by `n` (for strings will append `n` to the string)

Answer (score 0):

'Vomit IT - Chunky Mess' is very succinct, but, since we all love the plethora of ways to do stuff in PowerShell; here are a couple of other options for you to hack at.

```
$TotalHours = [System.TimeSpan]::new( 0 )

([string]$list = ('06:33','07:29','11:54')).Split() | 
ForEach-Object{ $TotalHours = $TotalHours.Add( $PSItem ) }
"$([Math]::Truncate($TotalHours.TotalHours)):$($TotalHpurs.Minutes)"


# Results
<#
25:56
#>

$Hour = (([TimeSpan[]]$TimeSpans = @(([string]$list = ('06:33','07:29','11:54')).Split())) | 
Measure-Object -Property TotalHours -Sum)

"$([Math]::Truncate($hour.Sum)):$([Math]::Round(($Hour.Sum - [Math]::Truncate($hour.Sum)) * 60))"

# Results
<#
25:56
#>


$Hour = [Math]::Truncate(($decimalHour = [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([decimal[]]@(
([TimeSpan[]]$TimeSpans = @(([string]$list = ('06:33','07:29','11:54')).Split())).TotalHours))))

$minute = [Math]::Round(($decimalHour - $hour) * 60)

"$($Hour):$minute"

# Results
<#
25:56
#>
```